# Why root bash output is colored but `sudo ls` output is not?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, ls, alias

In bash (I am using Ubuntu 12.04) I get colored outputs either as root (after `sudo su`) or as a normal user.

I checked (after reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10750/why-is-debians-root-shell-colorless)) the files `.bashrc` for normal user and superuser and the options related to color are enabled for `ls` in `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` which makes sense.

But when using `sudo ls` I get no colored output at all. Why is that? and how to enable it permanently?

Comment: Try `sudo -i ls`.

Comment: @Cyrus, I got no output at all when typing `sudo -i ls`

Comment: Compare output of `sudo pwd` and `sudo -i pwd`.

Comment: @Cyrus, `sudo pwd` has `/home/user` as output. `sudo -i pwd` has `/root`

Comment: I suppose /root is empty and so you get no output with `sudo -i ls`.

Comment: @Cyrus, indeed /root was empty. I copied different files (with different colors) and directories to /root folder in order to check. The output of `sudo -i ls` as a normal user still has no color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27197/discussion-between-jessag-and-cyrus).

Comment: Please try what Eric Renouf suggested. Add `alias sudo='sudo '` to your ~/bashrc. Source your ~/.bashrc or logout and login again. After that it should work with `sudo ls`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reenable aliases as described at https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo

the short version is to add and alias for sudo as

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

to get it to check the rest of the command for aliases.  Otherwise, the `sudo` is check to see if it's an alias, it is not, so the rest of the alias checking ends.  If sudo is an alias and ends in a space though, the next parts will also be checked to see if they are aliases, which is what you need to get the `ls` alias to be evaluated